# Can't open custom select since React 18 was implemented on our web app

Tags: javascript, cypress

In our web app we use custom selects. These are made like this:
Before clicking on select it's just like this

```html
<div data-testid="CmdSimpleSelectValue-null" id="simpleSelect-customerId-closed" data-cy="simpleSelect-customerId" class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_form-control-labels__WN00R CmdSimpleSelect-module_form-control__pio52 icons-module_new-css-icon-dropdown__a-138"
  title=""><span class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_text-truncate__t2yRn" id="span-customerId-closed" title="Zvoľte zákazníka">Zvoľte zákazníka</span></div>
```

After clicking the dropdown options appear as divs:

```html
<div class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_b-dropdown__content__xlH-Q" style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <ul class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_b-dropdown__list__AlyR0 CmdSimpleSelect-module_simple-list__WGq0-">
    <li>
      <a href="#" title="Zvoľte zákazníka" class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_item__0fz-l" data-cy="simpleSelect-customerId-" data-value=""><span class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_text-truncate__t2yRn">Zvoľte zákazníka </span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" title="TEST - Commander Services s.r.o." class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_item__0fz-l" data-cy="simpleSelect-customerId-793" data-value="793"><span class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_text-truncate__t2yRn">TEST - Commander Services s.r.o. (TCM)
    </span>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" title="Direct pojišťovna, a.s." class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_item__0fz-l" data-cy="simpleSelect-customerId-50022" data-value="50022">
        <span class="CmdSimpleSelect-module_text-truncate__t2yRn">Direct pojišťovna, a.s. (DRCP)
    </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So a bunch of divs.

So i can't use select functions and have to go by clicking the select and then the dropdown appears and i choose and option.

Before updating to React version 18 i had no problem with this. Since React 18 Cypress goes through the clicking on the select but doesn't open the dropdown afterwards.

My FE devs don't know how to fix it and we can't make them into regulars selects

This is pretty much the version that worked pre-React 18

```js
cy.get("[data-cy=simpleSelect-customerId]")
  .should('exist')
  .click({
    force: true
  });

cy.get('[data-cy="simpleSelect-customerId-' + vehicles.CustomerTest_id + '"]')
  .should('exist')
  .click();
```

The first get is where the problem lies as it passes with no problem. The next get can't see the dropdown so it fails.

I tried all i knew, triggers, mousovers focus then click, all kinds of waits in all kinds of places, double clicks, clicking on coordinates.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom, a fixed what i could :)